# Find a 12-gon and 33-gon that tessellate the plane

Tags: geometry

Not sure how to approach this. I think both figures have to be non convex in order for this to occur. I created a 12-gon using four house pentagons and it tessellates but I'm lost with the 33-gon.

Any suggestions will be of help. Thank you.

Comment: The simplest solution I can find is: $3 = 3\times 12 - 33$. Just imagine what you will get if you inscribe a "circle" inside a triangle.

Comment: Have you tried modifying two edges of a regular triangle correspondingly?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there is a term for this, but you can modify two neighbouring edges of an equilateral triangle correspondingly so that it still match a copy of itself. Take the following as an example, if you keep adding vertices along both edges for 15 times (keeping the base intact), you can get a 33-gon.

[image]

You can check that six copies of this gives a regular hexagon, which can tile a plane. (OK, you can modify the base as long as it is still rotationally symmetric)

For the 12-gon, try modifying parallel edges of a square.

Comment: Nice pictures! +1